# Reliability mechanisms in different IMAP servers

Tags: imap

I've occasionally been burned when using IMAP to move messages from one folder to another - basically, having messages disappear into the ozone.

One would think that a server would copy, confirm, then delete - but that doesn't seem to be the case, at least for some IMAP servers.

Does anybody have a sense of how the various IMAP servers actually handle moves?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a transactional issue — basically, your client and server combination did not treat the move as a transaction.

I guess it depends more on the client than on the server, but the one IMAP server that I know of that is strong in the database side, being based on [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org/), is [Archiveopteryx](http://archiveopteryx.org/).  Perhaps it will deal better with the server side, but it probably will do nothing for you if you problem is client-side.

Comment: Isn’t the answer useful for you, @MilesFidelman ?

Comment: Sadly, the OP hasn't been seen since the day (s)he asked the question (click on his/ her username and check "Last seen" in the profile).  I'm afraid your answer, like so many good ones, just disappears into the void of people who want help but can't be bothered to play the game.  +1 from me, though, if it makes you feel any better.